# How to write file inside folder in current directory using fopen

Tags: c, fopen

I want to write to a file, that is inside a folder in the current working directory, with the file name being the number value that is passed to the function.

```
void record_data(number[]) {
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("./folder/number", "w");
}
```

I'm unable to do so in this way (it names the file as `number`).

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Do you mean record_data( int number )?

Comment: This is invalid `(number[])` in C.

Comment: If you mean `void record_data(const char number[])` (so you pass the number as a string), then you need to concatenate the `./folder/` string with the number (`snprintf()` into a local variable) and pass the concatenated value to `fopen()`.  If you pass the number as an `int` (`void record_data(int number)`), then you still need to use `snprintf()` to format the file name into a local variable and pass that to `fopen()`, but the format will be different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you meant `int number` as opposed to your `number[]` which is not valid C.

You can use `sprintf()`, or preferably `snprintf()`:

```
void record_data(int number) {
    char str[255]; //Large enough buffer.
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "./folder/%d", number);
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(str, "w");
}
```

And consider calling `fclose()` on your `FILE *` when you're done using it.